# JS - How to split a string with more commas than I want

Tags: javascript

I have a string with a list of items. The items in the list contain strings which represent numbers.

```
var list = '"One","Two","3,842","3,549","3,653","4,443","3,994","3,935"'
```

I tried splitting like so:

```
list.split(',')
// result: [""One"", ""Two"", ""3", "842"", ""3", "549"", ""3", "653"", ""4", "443"", ""3", "994"", ""3", "935""]
```

Which is not what I intended.

I would like:

```
["One","Two","3,842","3,549","3,653","4,443","3,994","3,935"]
// or even better:
["One", "Two", 3842, 3549, 3653, 4443, 3994, 3935]
```

How do I correctly split this string into an array like above?

Comment: This will likely help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data

Comment: The method for reading a CSV helps out as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Try this](https://jsfiddle.net/ogu1yyhb/):

```
var list = '"One","Two","3,842","3,549","3,653","4,443","3,994","3,935"'
var split = JSON.parse("[" + list + "]");
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need

```
list.split(',"').map(function(e) { 
  return e.replace(/"|,/g, '');
});
```

to make sure `,` is always followed by a `"`, and then remove any extra `"` or `,` then the result will be:

```
["One", "Two", "3842", "3549", "3653", "4443", "3994", "3935"]
```

Comment: I get one extra quote mark at the end of each item in the array this way. `[""One"", "Two"", "3,842"", "3,549"", "3,653"", "4,443"", "3,994"", "3,935""]`

Comment: Though it does split the string.

Comment: Remove the quotes around each element after you split them.

Comment: @Barmar, I would like to do less processing rather than more.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do a match of the elements inside the quotes?

```
var list = '"One","Two","3,842","3,549","3,653","4,443","3,994","3,935"';
var elems = list.match(/"[^"]*"/g);
```

A lengthier version with a capture group (this one doesn't have the extra double quotes):

```
var list = '"One","Two","3,842","3,549","3,653","4,443","3,994","3,935"',
    re = /"([^"]*)"/g,
    arr = [],
    result;

while(result = re.exec(list)){
        arr.push(result[1]);
}
```